# How to add license key for fusion charts in angular2

Tags: angular, fusioncharts, license-key

As explained here in fusion charts documentation, it doesn't work for angular. How can I implement this for the angular projects?

[Fusion chart license](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG7BO.png)

FusionCharts.options.license({
key: '',
creditLabel: false,
});

Comment: Page not found.

Comment: What is the error that you get? Also where are you placing that bit of code to activate the licensing? It should be defined in the module file where you import and declare the FusionChartsModule.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code into your app.module.ts

FusionCharts.options['license']({
key: '',
creditLabel: false,
});

NB:If Still error occurs the please check your tsconfig.json and trun off the strict : true option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below steps to use your licensed version of FusionCharts:

1. Create a folder named fusioncharts in your project root or elsewhere and copy the library module files of your licensed version of FusionCharts into that folder.
2. Install the angular2-fusioncharts wrapper:

   npm install angular2-fusioncharts --save

After installing angular2-fusioncharts, import it in your Angular AppModule as follows:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular4-fusioncharts';
import * as FusionCharts from './fusioncharts';
import * as Charts from './fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
import * as FintTheme from './fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FintTheme);
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FusionChartsModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Once the library is imported, you can use this component in your Angular application:

In your Angular AppComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent {
        id = 'chart1';
        width = 600;
        height = 400;
        type = 'column2d';
        dataFormat = 'json';
        dataSource;
        title = 'Angular4 FusionCharts Sample';
        constructor() {
            this.dataSource = {
                "chart": {
                    "caption": "Harry's SuperMart",
                    "subCaption": "Top 5 stores in last month by revenue",
                    "numberprefix": "$",
                    "theme": "fint"
                },
                "data": [
                    {
                        "label": "Bakersfield Central",
                        "value": "880000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Garden Groove harbour",
                        "value": "730000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Los Angeles Topanga",
                        "value": "590000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Compton-Rancho Dom",
                        "value": "520000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Daly City Serramonte",
                        "value": "330000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, You can use  component in your app.component.html template:

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<fusioncharts
    [width]="width"
    [height]="height"
    [type]="type"
    [dataFormat]="dataFormat"
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
></fusioncharts>
```

Check this document - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/upgrading/license-activation